# How to change field setting using on some condition based?

Tags: 7, entities

I want to change image property like resolution based on other field.Like I have a field that tells how the image will be shown. If I select a large image then minimum image resolution have to change higher.

There is no option to do it with conditional field. So Is there any other way?

Comment: I'm afraid there is not, but if you have like 4 available display settings, why don't you just add 4 fields, each wit one? And then just use dropdown field to select which one is supposed to be shown?

Comment: Ya that is a good idea but I have to change most of the things that I already done. So I want to change only  setting. If there is any module or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked my condition pragmatically in `hook_node_validate` function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for [Formatter Field](https://drupal.org/project/formatter_field):

> The formatter field module provides a mechanism for specifying a formatter and formatter settings to be used for displaying a field, on a per-entity basis. By default, Drupal provides formatters and settings per entity bundle, but in certain situations it is necessary to choose the formatter at the entity level.
>
> For example, say you have a page **node with an image field**. Normally, you would select an image style as the formatter, and all page nodes would use that same image style. With this module, you can add a formatter field to page nodes, which is hooked up to the image field. **Then when the node is created or edited, the image style can be selected per-node**.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Does this module will checks validation for minimum resolution of images.

Comment: @SumitMadan if you will require minimum resolution and prevent upscaling in your formats, it should.

Comment: Prevent upscaling only controls the image cache I think not the validation of resolution.

Comment: @SumitMadan well, right. See if it would allow you to save node if Allow Upscaling is false and image is to small. I'm sure it will not or there is a module that will prevent it - either way I've seen it work even if I can't recall all the pieces now.

Comment: ok I am testing it.

Comment: naah, It doesn't meet my requiments. It is not validating the image resultion.

Comment: @SumitMadan Sorry to hear that. You may need to write your own module for that, in this case. Unless I can find the one I was using, but I don't work for that site any longer so it might not be easy.

Comment: ok sure. thanks. Could you mail me the attachment if you found that?

Comment: If I'll find it, I'll either post a link or code here.